# How to update Identity database to version 2.0.0.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a project wich i was managing my users and roles using the `AspNet.Identity 1.0.0.0` i update to version `2.0.0.0` to enable-migrations and add some custom properties to my `UserModel`. But now im getting this error when try to add a new user:

```
Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
```

How can i fix it?
 i can create a new database becouse i dont need the users data that i created before.

The steps i did:

```
   1)Update the AspNet.Identity to 2.0.0.0 via nuget
    2)Add some properties to my UserModel
    3)Add-Migration "CustomProperties"
    4)Update-Database
```

The Update-Database should create the new columns, right?

Comment: Did you add those columns to your database when you upgraded from 1 to 2?

Comment: @DavidG I posted the steps i did in the OP. Thanks

Comment: Did the migration contain these extra columns? It should have code like this `AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Email", c => c.String());`

Comment: @DavidG just add it to the Up() method? and keep the Down() method clear?

Comment: I'm asking if the `add-migration` command did that for you?

Comment: No, both methods are empty

Comment: And if you run `Add-Migration "CustomProperties"` again to rescaffold it, does anything get added?

Comment: @DavidG nothing, clear again. Is there a way to recreate all the identity database with the corresponding 2.0.0.0 version columns?

Comment: @DavidG I deleted all the tables on the database, delete the migrations folder, create it all again, and now it seems to work

Comment: Great news, I knew there was something up with the migrations.

Comment: @ggui: Glad you figured it out. Please post what you did to solve the problem as an answer, and then accept it, so this question doesn't continue to show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, i tried to create new migration configuration and the methods are empty:

```
public void Up()
{
}

public void Down()
{
}
```

So i deleted all the identity tables of my DB, deleted the `Migrations` folder in the solution explorer and then remake the whole proccess i told on the OP. Now the migrations methods are like:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.RoleId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ClaimType = c.String(),
                    ClaimValue = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
            c => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
    }
```

And now i can create users, roles, etc.
Thanks